# Laravel Backpack: Show a Many to Many relationship in Show Operation

Tags: laravel-backpack

Couldn't find this [in the docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs).

Is there any standard way, without creating a custom widget, or overriding the view template, to show a Many to Many relationships in a CRUD's showOperation in Backpack for Laravel? If the answer is NO, what would be your approach to implement it?

Let's say I have a Course Model, and a User model, and there is a Many to Many between both

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'course_students');
    }
}


class User extends Model
{
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_students');
    }
}
```

In the Show Operation for the Course. How do I show a Table with all students?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can use the [relationship](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#relationship) column for this

Excerpt:

> Output the related entries, no matter the relationship:
>
> 1-n relationships - outputs the name of its one connected entity;
>
> n-n relationships - enumerates the names of all its connected entities;
>
> Its name and definition is the same as for the relationship field
> type:

```
[  
   // any type of relationship
   'name'         => 'tags', // name of relationship method in the model
   'type'         => 'relationship',
   'label'        => 'Tags', // Table column heading
   // OPTIONAL
   // 'entity'    => 'tags', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
   // 'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
   // 'model'     => App\Models\Category::class, // foreign key model
],
```

> Backpack tries to guess which attribute to show for the related item.
> Something that the end-user will recognize as unique. If it's
> something common like "name" or "title" it will guess it. If not, you
> can manually specify the attribute inside the column definition, or
> you can add public $identifiableAttribute = 'column_name'; to your
> model, and Backpack will use that column as the one the user finds
> identifiable. It will use it here, and it will use it everywhere you
> haven't explicitly asked for a different attribute.